# Crear una ventana como en GMAIL

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo un botón que al darle clic muestre una ventana de bajo, como GMAIL:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale lo de mostrarlo, pero no puedo alinearlo de tal manera que quede como en la imagen. Este es mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boton_ventana').on('click', function() {
    $('.ventana_flotante').toggle();
    //$('.ventana_flotante').toggle('slow');
    if ($('.ventana_flotante').css('display') == 'block') {
      $('.btn').css({
        "border-bottom": "3px solid #ff676d"
      });
      $('.boton').css({
        "font-weight": "bold"
      });
    } else {
      $('.btn').css({
        "border-bottom": "0"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.contenedor_boton {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 500px;
  float: right;
  right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff676d;
}

.boton:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.ventana_flotante {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*coloes*/
  padding: 10px 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 125px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="contenedor_boton col-auto">
    <div class="boton_ventana">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default boton">Cliente</button>
    </div>
    <div class="ventana_flotante">
      <div class="caja">
        CAJA
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que puedes hacer es usar el drop-down de bootstrap y usando row,col,justify-content y algunos estilos mas podras alinearlo como deseas ♥